# Property '$' of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website which eventually is a streaming radio website. on the header i have a script that is pulling streaming data (like listeners count and currently playing) from my Dedicated server's CP..(Centova Cast)

I registered the script in the function.php:

this is the register

> wp_register_script( ’streaminfo’,
>   'http://94.23.250.14:2199/system/streaminfo.js',false,null);
>                   wp_enqueue_script( ’streaminfo’ );

This is the the whole jQuery section for you to review..

```
/* ------------------------------------

:: INITIATE JQUERY / STYLING

------------------------------------ */

function init_dynscripts() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

        if ( function_exists('bp_is_blog_page')) {
            if (!bp_is_blog_page()) {
                wp_enqueue_script( 'bp-js', BP_PLUGIN_URL . '/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc/global.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
            }
        }

        wp_register_style('northvantage-style', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'),false,null);
        wp_enqueue_style('northvantage-style');


        if(get_option('enable_responsive')!='disable') :

        wp_register_style('northvantage-responsive', get_template_directory_uri().'/stylesheets/responsive.css',false,null);
        wp_enqueue_style('northvantage-responsive');

        endif;  

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core',false,null);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs',false,null);
        wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-accordion",false,null);
        wp_enqueue_script("swfobject",false,null);
        wp_deregister_script("jquery-effects-core");

        wp_deregister_script('libertas');   
        wp_register_script('libertas',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/nv-script.pack.js',false,null);
        wp_enqueue_script('libertas');  
        wp_register_script( ’streaminfo’, 'http://94.23.250.14:2199/system/streaminfo.js',false,null);
        wp_enqueue_script( ’streaminfo’ );
        wp_register_script( ’jpie’, get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jpie.js',false,null);
        wp_enqueue_script( ’jpie’ );
        wp_register_style('jpiestyle', get_template_directory_uri().'/jpie.css',false,null);
        wp_enqueue_style('jpiestyle');


        if(get_option('jwplayer_js')) { // Check jw player javascript file is present

        $NV_jwplayer_js = get_option('jwplayer_js');

        wp_deregister_script( 'jw-player' );    
        wp_register_script( 'jw-player', $NV_jwplayer_js,false,null);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jw-player' );       
        }
    }
}    
add_action('init', 'init_dynscripts',100);


function _remove_script_version( $src ){ // remove script version
    $parts = explode( '?', $src );
    return $parts[0];
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```

It appears i have a conflict between streaminfo.js and my website. 
element inspection gives:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a
>   function

To make things short..everything i tried with the file ended up wrong.

i tried changing every $ sign to jQuery in the file, it eliminate the conflict but created conflicts with other files.

i tried adding

> jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

to the head of the file but it breaks other elements on the CP.

Eventually i ran a simple test and created a webpage with only this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<span id="cc_strinfo_title_tranceilfm" class="cc_streaminfo"></span>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://94.23.250.14:2199/system/streaminfo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the page didn't return any errors. (i did include a path to the google jQuery file)

Something in Wordpress is messing up with the jQuery plugin? or some string is missing in my code?

> www.tranceil.fm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding `jQuery.noConflict()` at the top of your document.ready. This will unbind the `$` variable, which should get rid of your conflicts.

In response to our discussion in comments, and to help anyone else who sees this question, here's a little bit of overview:

**How jQuery and jQuery.noConflicts() work:**

When you load the jQuery library, a variable called `jQuery` is created, which represents the "jQuery" function. An alias to`jQuery` , named `$`, is also created.

For whatever reason, several other javascript libraries change the `$` alias to represent their own functions. When this happens, you have a conflict, as two different things are trying to have control of the `$` variable. What jQuery.noConflict() does is unassociates `$` with `jQuery`, allowing whatever else is trying to use `$` to use it freely.

The catch is that now `$` doesn't refer to `jQuery`, so everywhere you want to access the jQuery object, you need to use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: like so? jQuery.noConflict(document).ready(function ($){ what should i close that with? http://94.23.250.14:2199/system/streaminfo.js

Comment: like this: jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery.noConflict(); });

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of null  :(

Comment: you also need to keep all of the $'s changed to jQuery, except for the ones that refer to whatever other library is trying to use `$`

Comment: ummm..a bit new to this..can you make an example of library call to $?

Comment: well, you shouldn't have any direct calls to external library functions, so really changing every `$` to `jQuery` in your code should work now

Comment: Still getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of null    (thanx for sticking up with me lol..again, pretty new to this) i changed every $ to jQuery maybe my closing? http://94.23.250.14:2199/system/streaminfo.js

Comment: you forgot to change the document.ready function back to the way i had it. make it look exactly like this:  jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery.noConflict(); }); with all of your code being after jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: i double checked..and i believe i did that correctly ..if you look at the file you'l see its exactly as you suggested..

Comment: @user1562911 are you sure? the first line of that file looks like this: `jQuery.noConflict(document).ready(function ($) {)` which is the way you had it at first, before I suggested changing it

Comment: im not sure why are you seeing this, might be cache? http://i47.tinypic.com/2rghrwo.png

Comment: ok, gotcha. Hmm.. do a global search for ".match" to see what is trying to call it

Comment: found 2 calls..var b=e.match(/^cc_strinfo_([a-z]+)_/);if(b){this.registry[d].id[b[1]]=e}},load:function()       and      if(!a.match(/^https?:\/\//i)){a=window.location.href
}this.url=a.replace(/(\.(?:[a-z]{2,}|[0-9]+)(:[0-9]+)?\/).*jQuery/i,"jQuery1");

Comment: what files are those in? yours? or external libraries

Comment: no, you're good. ok, for both of those, you need to figure out where `e` (in the first one) and `a` (in the second one) are initialized. More than likely, they're set to use the value of `$`, which since you added the noConflict() call, is undefined. Then, assuming they *are* set to `$`, just change them to be set to `jQuery`.

Comment: i tried looking for those as much as my knowledge guides me..is this what you ment? var e=g.song;if(e&&e!=this.registry[h].current_song){this.get_streaminfo_element(h,"song").fadeOut("fast",function(){jQuery(this).html(e);jQuery(this).fadeIn("fast")});this.registry[h].current_song=e}}},handle_json:function(a){if(!a){return}

Comment: I didnt exactly got what to change..$ signes are not in the file since i changed them..but i do have a backup of the original..would this help?

Comment: bleh. that's what I was afraid of. That means it's null because something *else*, in this case somewhere inside the code for `g`, possibly even deeper than that, doesn't have access to jQuery. Who knows where it is. Just for kicks, try adding an alert(jQuery) right before `var e = g.song;` just to see if the `$` issue is even the root cause

Comment: yeah, if you can send me a the backup I'll do my best on it

Comment: I dont know if i should post it here so i sent the file to your facebook inbox ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14759/discussion-between-phillip-schmidt-and-user1562911)